# Hazelcast client threads

Tags: hazelcast

I am using java client to connect to a hazelcast cluster.
Everytime I connect to a cluster, I observe that about 5 client-thread(s) are created on member's jvm.
These threads hang around for about 30-40 seconds before they are destroyed.
What are these these threads ? How can I control the number of client-thread(s) created ?

I am using hazelcast-all.3.3.3

Comment: Just out of curiosity; how often is a client connection to the cluster? Even if  a few threads are created, this should be a one time issue.

Comment: We use hazelcast java client as an interface to the cluster of our tooling. I noticed that a lot of threads are created by hazelcast, I found information about other threads in the documentation. I could not find information about client threads.

Answer (score 0):

I had a peek and I see a few client threads[image]

But these threads are 'permanent'. They can be configured using the ClientProperties. In this case the 'event threads' are the the largest number of threads and can be controlled with the PROP_EVENT_THREAD_COUNT field.

This is based on Hazelcast 3.5 btw. I have not checked for 3.3.3.

What are the threads you are seeing shortly; do you know their names? This makes it a bit easier to figure out what kind of threads they are. And why is it an issue?

Comment: Hi pveentjer,                                                                                             The threads I see shortly when I connect to a cluster using java client end with _client.thread-1, _client.thread-2, _client.thread-3, _client-thread-4, _client.thread-5.

Comment: Could you try with 3.5? A lot has changed on the client side. I'm not an expert. Deal mostly with the serverside. But why is it an issue that these threads are created?

Comment: It was an issues earlier because we were exceeding thread limit in unix, we have now increased this limit. I wanted to understand what these threads are and if there is a way to configure them. I will get back to you when we upgrade to 3.5. Thanks.